# VB.Net Remove Everything After Third Hyphen

Tags: regex, vb.net

Here is the string I am looking to modify:
**170-0175-00B**-BEARING PLATE MACHINING.asm:2

I want to keep "**170-0175-00B**". So I need to remove the third hyphen and whatever is after it.

Comment: Is the third hyphen also always the LAST hyphen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rapid solution

```
string test = "170-0175-00B-BEARING PLATE MACHINING.asm:2";
int num = 2;
int index = test.IndexOf('-');
while(index > 0 && num > 0)
{
    index = test.IndexOf('-', index+1);
    num--;
}
if(index > 0)
    test = test.Substring(0, index);
```

of course, if you are searching for the last hyphen then is more simple to do

```
int index = test.LastIndexOf('-');
if(index > 0)
    test = test.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I didn't notice you guys replied so fast so I was working on my own solution in the meantime. Finally, I got it (I'll post it tomorrow when I am able to reply to my post).

Comment: Difficult to predict, but usually the answers come very quickly

Answer (score 4):

What about some LINQ?

```
Dim str As String = "170-0175-00B-BEARING PLATE MACHINING.asm:2"
MsgBox(String.Join("-"c, str.Split("-"c).Take(3)))
```

With this approach, you can take anything out after Nth hyphen, where N is easily controlled (a const).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
regex.Replace(sourcestring,"^((?:[^-]*-){2}[^-]*).*","$1",RegexOptions.Singleline))
```

You may not want the Singleline option though, depending how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much for such fast replies.

Here's the path that I took:

```
FormatDessinName("170-0175-00B-BEARING PLATE MACHINING.asm:2")


Private Function FormatDessinName(DessinName As String)
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(DessinName, "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]([0-9]+)?") 'Matches 000-0000-00A(optional numbers after the last letter)
    Dim formattedName As String = ""

    If match.Success Then 'Returns true or false
        formattedName = match.Value 'Returns the actual matched value
    End If

    Return formattedName
End Function
```

Works great!